# Search form shortcode redirects to shortcode tag istead of ?s

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a search form for a page and placed it in a function that gets shortcoded. But the issue is that the action of the form goes to the shortcode tag instead of ?s. For example if I do a search it will redirect to

**http://www.domain.com/?search-course-provider=course+6&providers=product_cat&post_type=product**

instead of

**http://www.domain.com/?s=course&providers=product_cat&post_type=product**

`?s` becomes `?search-course-provider`. How can I fix this issue.

```
function search_course_provider() {
?>
    <div style="background: #f4f4f4; height: 150px" class="container-fluid">
        <div  class="container">
            <form action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform" class="center-block-page">
                <input id="search-course-provider" type="text" placeholder="What do you want to study?" name="search-course-provider" value="">
                <input type="submit" id="enter" alt="waiting" value="">
                <input type="hidden" value="product_cat" name="providers" />
                <input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_shortcode('search-course-provider', 'search_course_provider');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `<input id="search-course-provider" type="text" placeholder="What do you want to study?" name="search-course-provider" value="">` to `<input id="search-course-provider" type="text" placeholder="What do you want to study?" name="s" value="">`

Comment: BTW, if I want to search and output only the taxonomies related to the product, what input type hidden should I add / remove.Taxonomy is `product_cat` and needs to match in the ?s. Actually it doesn't need to be a product.

Comment: You mean classify the product? based on what?

Comment: like when I search, I search for example course 3(product or anything), and what to output the course provider(taxonomy) related to this course, but to output only the taxonomy not the product.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74726/discussion-between-user3467855-and-niranjan-s).

Answer (score 1):

That's because the name attribute of your input is `search-course-provider` change this to `s` and it shal go to the second URL